# How do I extend the character limit of a string in management studio

Tags: cursors

The SQL below works to an extend however when I view the output in SSMS tables with a lot of columns appear to be getting cut of in that the string that is generated by the cursor only appears to go to a maximum limit.

```
    USE [HealthBI]
GO

/*** ENTER VIEW SCHEMA ***/
DECLARE @schema_name AS varchar(MAX) = 'trust'

/*** ENTER CDO TABLE TO REPLICATE ***/
DECLARE @table_name_value  AS varchar(MAX) = 'CDO[_]%'
DECLARE @table_name  AS varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @column_name AS varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @viewsql AS varchar(MAX)

DECLARE csr_view CURSOR FOR
SELECT TABLE_NAME ,
STUFF(( SELECT  ',' +QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)+'.'+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_NAME = a.TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME 
FOR XML PATH(''),Type)
    .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)' ), 1, 1, '') AS value
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
where  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND TABLE_NAME like @table_name_value
    and TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'CDO_CDS%'
GROUP BY a.TABLE_NAME

    OPEN csr_view
        FETCH NEXT FROM csr_View INTO @TABLE_NAME, @column_name
    SET @viewsql = ''
--  PRINT @TABLE_NAME PRINT @column_name

        WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
        BEGIN

        IF OBJECT_ID('['+ @schema_name + '].[' + @table_name + ']') IS NULL
        SET @viewsql = @viewsql + '
        CREATE '
        ELSE
        SET @viewsql = @viewsql + '
        ALTER '

        SET @viewsql = @viewsql + 'VIEW [' + @schema_name + '].[' + @table_name + ']
        AS SELECT ' + @column_name + '
        FROM [dbo].[' + @table_name + ']'


        IF @schema_name = 'trust' AND @table_name <> 'CDO_MPI'
        SET @viewsql = @viewsql + '
        INNER JOIN [CDO_MPI]
        ON [CDO_MPI].[UNIQUE_ID] = [' + @table_name + '].[CDO_MPI_UNIQUE_ID]
        AND [CDO_MPI].[IS_DUMMY_PATIENT] = ''N''   GO'

        IF @schema_name = 'trust' AND @table_name = 'CDO_MPI'
        SET @viewsql = @viewsql + '
        WHERE [CDO_MPI].[IS_DUMMY_PATIENT] = ''N'''
        PRINT (@viewsql)
--       EXEC (@viewsql)

        FETCH NEXT FROM csr_View INTO @TABLE_NAME, @column_name
        SET @viewsql = ''

        END
    CLOSE csr_view
DEALLOCATE csr_View
```

Comment: In SSMS have you tried dragging the column divider to the right to increase the onscreen display ? Have you cut and pasted the data to ensure that all of the data is returned? Do you have a screen shot of you issue ?

Comment: There is something online about SSMS results only displaying 8000 characters, when i use PRINT (@viewsql) anything over than that gets knocked/chopped/cut off, however when I use SELECT (@viewsql) its fine but hten displays all the tables in a different results window. I need the output of the above code to be complete so I can past it into SSMS for review.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here ?

Comment: Create a views for all tables for the criteria I used above, however I wouldn't want to keep updating views each time a table column is added etc, so using the Information Schema table to generate a script that will create the views dynamically. The above works but as i say very large tables are not output correctly in the results window in SSMS

Comment: Is this issue related only to the PRINT command?

Comment: Yes it is just related to the PRINT command? Works fine when changed to a select

Answer (score 1):

change  `PRINT (@viewsql)` to  `SELECT (@viewsql)`

Answer (score 1):

You're running up against the limitation of the `PRINT` command which, I believe, is limited to 8000 characters.

A fix in your situation, because it looks like you're script output contains `\r\n` characters, is to replace:

```
PRINT (@viewsql)
```

with the following:

```
DECLARE @printCur INT
SET @printCur = 8000

WHILE LEN(@viewsql) > 8000
BEGIN
     SET     @printCur = 8000 - CHARINDEX(CHAR(10) + CHAR(13), REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@viewsql, 0, 8000)))

     PRINT LEFT(@viewsql, @printCur)
     SELECT @viewsql = RIGHT(@viewsql, LEN(@viewsql) - @printCur)
END
```

This will iterate through your `@viewsql` variable and print out the commands using line breaks (i.e. `\r\n`) as potential delimiter points in the string.  I use this on a routine I coded to print out database role definitions and it hasn't failed me yet.

Hope that helps!